# ADXL345 to detect sudden and large changes in acceleration

Tags: adafruit

I am working on school project to develop, basically, a shock sensor when the object containing the ADXL345 is thrown to the ground.

I have used the Adafruit ADXL345 sensortest from the library but I am not sure how to code it such that the reading will only appear when there is a sudden and large change in in acceleration in either the x/y/z direction.

Any tips on how to do so?

Comment: same way that you would code it so that a reading only appears when you press a button

Answer (score 0):

Build an enclosure for the Arduino and the sensor in such a way that you
can keep connected the USB cable that links the Arduino to the computer.
Then run the [sensortest sketch](https://github.com/adafruit/Adafruit_ADXL345/blob/master/examples/sensortest/sensortest.ino) provided as an example with the
library, and look at (or better yet, record) the acceleration data.

Now turn the enclosure around, shake it, hit it, drop it to the
ground... all while monitoring the sensor's output. I recommend that you
plot the acceleration curves: it should make things clearer. What do you
see? Can you tell the difference between the enclosure being dropped to
the floor and other forms of shaking just by looking at the output data?
How do you tell the difference? Is it the magnitude of the acceleration
or is it the rate of change? If you think the rate of change is more
relevant, then modify the sketch in order to also print this rate of
change. In either case, can you find a threshold of magnitude (or rate
of change) of acceleration that could be used to discriminate between a
drop and other forms of movement? If so, write it down.

I am asking all the questions above to show you the path to solving your
problem. The purpose is not only to have you do all the work: *I do not
have the answers* to those questions, and you will really have to do all
this work yourself.

You should be able to come up with a criterion of the form: the object
has been dropped if such function of the measured acceleration is higher
than such threshold. The function would likely be either the Euclidean
norm of the acceleration or the Euclidean norm of its time derivative (I
cannot tell which is better). Now code the function in your sketch, then
you can write something like:

```cpp
if (computed_criterion >= drop_threshold) {
    signal_that_the_object_has_been_dropped();
}
```